Swagger no me funciona en aws ec2
Tengo mi API Rest con SpringBoot en aws, ya esta en producción y funciona de forma correcta, pero he añadido:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version> <!-- o la última versión estable de la serie 2.x -->
</dependency>

tambien he añadido esto en mis properties y sigue sin funcionar:
springdoc.api-docs.enabled=true
springdoc.swagger-ui.enabled=true

Alguien sabe el por qué si mi api esta funcionando de forma correcta la documentación no aparece?
Se agradece la ayuda.

Luego de agregar la última versión de la dependencia (que por cierto, es la 2.6.0), tienes que realizar un maven clean install para que la dependencia se descargue en el proyecto. El resto al menos yo lo veo bien.
